# Linear regression of 2 observations in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to do a simple regression based on two observations:

```
> x=c(1,2)
> y=c(3,5)
> fit <- lm(y ~ x)
> Prediction <- predict(fit, newdata=c(3,4))
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
ALL 2 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        1         NA      NA       NA
x                  2         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

I know that I'm not supposed to get any residuals in my model but why can't I predict future values for x?

Answer (score 2):

I think that newdata needs to be in a `list()` form.

```
predict(fit, newdata=list(x=c(3,4)))
```

Comment: `newdata` is a `data.frame` representing the variables on the right side of the formula. To be fair, `data.frame`s are a special case of `list`.